# access base class variable in derived class

Tags: c#, variables, radix, derived

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        baseClass obj = new baseClass();
        obj.intF = 5;
        obj.intS = 4;
        child obj1 = new child();
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(obj.addNo()));
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(obj1.add()));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
public class baseClass
{
    public int intF = 0, intS = 0;
    public int addNo()
    {
        int intReturn = 0;
        intReturn = intF + intS;
        return intReturn;
    }
}
class child : baseClass
{
    public int add()
    {
        int intReturn = 0;
        intReturn = base.intF * base.intS;
        return intReturn;
    }
}
```

I want to access intF and intS in child class whatever i input.. but i always get the values of both variables 0. 0 is default value of both variables.

Can anyone tell me that how can i get the value???

thx in adv..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Zero is what you should get, since you made single instance of child class and did not assign any value to its inherited variables,

```
child obj1 = new child();
```

rather you have instantiated another instance of base class separately and assign value to its members,

```
baseClass obj = new baseClass();
```

both runtime both the base class instance and child instance are totally different objects, so you should assign the child values separately like

```
obj1.intF = 5;
obj1.intS = 4;
```

then only you shall get the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

You've got two *separate* objects - that's the problem. The values of the base class variables in the object referred to by `obj1` *are* 0, because they haven't been set to anything else. There's nothing to tie that object to the object referred to by `obj`.

If you need to access the variables of another object, you'd have to make that object available to the one trying to access the data. You could pass `obj` as an argument to a method, or perhaps make it a property. There are lots of different approaches here, but we don't know what the bigger picture is - what you're really trying to do. Once you understand why it's not working as you expect it to, you can start thinking about what you're *really* trying to do.

Just to be clear, this has nothing to do with inheritance. It has *everything* to do with you creating two distinct objects. You'd get the same effect if you just used a single class, but created two different instances of that class.

Comment: actually i want to do add two no and then multiply that nos with using inheritance.

Comment: @sam: How does inheritance come into play here? It's not like you're overriding any behaviour, or anything like that.