# How to access a base class value from derived class c#

Tags: c#

Can any one let me know "How to access base class variables in derived class"?

Example:

Class 1.cs Code

```
public class baseClass
{
    public int intF = 0, intS = 0;
    public int addNo()
    {
        int intReturn = 0;
        intReturn = intF + intS;
        return intReturn;
    }
}

Public class child : baseClass
{
    public int add()
    {
        int intReturn = 0;
        intReturn = base.intF * base.intS;
        return intReturn;
    }
}
```

Class2.cs Code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        baseClass obj = new baseClass();
        obj.intF = 5;
        obj.intS = 4;
        child obj1 = new child();
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(obj.addNo()));
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(obj1.add()));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The problem is in child class which gets inherited from base class..

The value of intF and intS is always showing as 0 instead of 5&4.

Can any one let me know where I am going wrong?

Regards,

G.V.N.Sandeep

Comment: Both answers are correct. The two easiest ways to get the expected result are: 1) declare obj as "baseClass obj = new child()" and delete the line where you create obj1 (it will always be default); and 2) declare intF and intS as "public static int"

Comment: Exact duplicate (why?): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296026/

Answer (score 3):

Instance fields `intF` and `intS` belong to... instance, not to a type. When you're setting them for `obj` instance, the same fields in `obj1` instance have their default values (zeroes).

You must assign 5 and 4 this way:

```
child obj1 = new child();
obj1.intF = 5;
obj1.intS = 4;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your fields are not `static`. There is one separate field for each instance (object) you create.

`obj` and `obj1` are distinct instances.

By the way, there's no need to use the `base` keyword in this situation. The two fields *are* in the `child` class because of inheritance. Only use `base` when the current class overrides or hides a member from the base class.